# Make "gaussian laser beam" (object with variable radial emission profile)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, mathematics

Laser beams are usually not cylinders of light, but instead they have a smooth beam profile, where they are brighter in the center of the beam and dimmer towards the sides. The cross section typically looks like a Gaussian function, do they are often called "[gaussian beams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam)".

Consequently, in illustrations, the lasers are often rendered such that they are most intense in the center and fade out towards the sides. I have achieved this using a blur effect in the compositor, but since Blender can handle most of the other physics in the world, I would like to include realistic laser beams directly.

Here is what I have come up with so far, but I am not quite happy with the results:

[image]

The blue beam was created using the node layout described [in this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23054/volume-emitter-that-is-more-intense-towards-the-outside-of-the-object), except that I swapped the order of the colors in the color ramp. This still displays very sharp edges and they do not match the natural background color.

[image]

For the green beam, I tried to do the most realistic thing possible: I combined a volume emitter with a volume scatterer object. In reality, it is the scattering of the laser beam by particles in the air that allows us to see the beam, so I thought that this was the most appropriate. I added a set of nodes (yellow) to control the longitudinal intensity of the emitter in order to make the beam brighter near the focus (right side). Then, I included a set of nodes (red) to control the radial intensity of the beam in order to give it a nice soft edge. However, I just scaled the intensity along the radial coordinate, but did not take into account the fact that the beam is getting smaller. So, there is a nice gradient of intensity near the left side of the beam, but it's still very sharp towards the right side.

So, I suppose the question is how do I scale the intensity of the emitter while taking into account the width of the beam?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a node setup that approximates the Gaussian beam.

- normalize the coordinates of the object by division on the dimensions
- subdivide the radial dimensions "in this case Y and Z" on the beam length "X"
- feed  Y Z into a [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gaussian_function&section=4#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function) to create the redial gradient
- the longitude gradient is simple (beam length-X)

[image: cycles node setup for Gaussian laser beam]

Coordinates node group
[image: Coordinates node group]

Gaussian function node group
[image: Gaussian function node group]
The **A** input in the Gaussian function group controls the amplitude of the Gaussian function.
**S_y** and **S_z** control the Y and Z spread.

simple render :[image: example render]

another render :

[image]
[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34375)
[YA render](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/83788)

Comment: Wow! i'm going to try and (i hope) understand this! thx!

Comment: changing the object's origin allows to define where is the thinest point. (can be one side or in the middle giving 2 cones of light)

Comment: @Bithur yes if download the file you can see that i have moved the origin to the end of the object , and it won't give two cones unless you take the absolute value of X

Comment: really fun!! now, question coming :)

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating how to implement the gaussian function - that is awesome. But are you taking into account that the width of the object is changing with x? It seems that you have the same problem that I did, where you are defining a width of the gaussian that stays constant regardless of how the object changes in x.

Comment: @DanHickstein YES i took in account the change of the width you can see that it fades on the sides from the origin to the end , the dimensions i defined are to normalize the dimension, also take a look at the additional render it is more clear than this , and check the blend file for more experiments

Comment: Hmmm, well, at the end of the day, I want it to look more like a nice blurry-edged laser beam and not like a cone with dark regions near the edges.

Comment: @DanHickstein an image for illustration would be apretiated

Comment: Maybe something closer to this image, where the lasers are just blurry light against the background. https://www.google.com/search?q=laser+beam+illustration&espv=2&biw=1401&bih=805&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=OCLhVKaWH5etyAT9xYHYDA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=2#imgdii=_&imgrc=yp3y-yWJFkEKrM%253A%3ByZtL9sQiFK5T4M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fthumb9.shutterstock.com%252Fdisplay_pic_with_logo%252F1895957%252F173410466%252Fstock-photo-the-beam-of-light-on-a-black-background-laser-illustration-173410466.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.shutterstock.com%252Fs%252Flaser-beam%252Fsearch.html%3B450%3B320

Comment: @DanHickstein but those look cylindrical, is that what you need?

Comment: Well, I wanted them to be conical, but this is just an example of how I would like them to look against the background. I don't want them to look like sharp cones, they should be blurry like in the above image.

Comment: the dark sharp edges are caused by the density of the scatter  which is added gust to demonstrate the brightness of the light beam; i will try to do another render

Comment: @DanHickstein check the additional render

Comment: Oh, that is exactly what I wanted! But I don't understand which step is normalizing the coordinates to the object's radial dimension. Can you indicate where that is in your answer?

Comment: @DanHickstein the second image "coordinates node group" , glade you liked it !

Comment: Does someone still have the original blender file of the proposed solution by Chebhu?