# A tube of light in a volume shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, node-editor, mathematics

As I had much fun with [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/make-gaussian-laser-beam-object-with-variable-radial-emission-profile#24678) (thx Chebhou) but gaussian functions are a bit too complex for me, i want my volume scatter cylinder to have simply a smaller cylinder emitting light inside it, from the same object/material. The same size all along, or why not being able to control the fading at one or both sides (why not asking :) )

It has to be done with math nodes, vectors and things like that (what I want to learn)

Something like this but in a single object
[image]

looks like a light saber :)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15711/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3640/1853

Comment: @cegaton nope, i don't want a compositing or modeling answer, it has to be shader maths. I already did (long ago) a light saber but i want to learn more about math nodes and vectors in materials. I hope this is simple enough for me to understand the why and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this circle equation and chose a radius "max R = 0.5" :

[image]

Coordinates node group :  [image]

and for fading on the sides i used a sin function :

[image]

render :
[image]

Comment: seems like what i wanted, checking details :)

Comment: the sin doesn't seem to fade the light, it just stops at both ends.

Comment: it fades but in short range that it's not clearly visible because that's how a sin wave is, you can replace with other functions

Comment: Max R=0.5 :) A max value of 1 would be for diameter.

Comment: yeah, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Variation on Chebhou's answer : Origin and dimension independant :
[image]

Not sure the sine works exactly the same.

Comment: that's brilliant ! it is dimension ,and origin dependent