# Blender material glare fx

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Can we somehow achieve glare effect (like that radio active material small thick glow around the object) on an object using just Cycles material nodes (this is my 2nd I guess better formulated approach with this question)?

Something like the "glowing" laser sabres on this image:
[image]

I understood it can be achieved thru Glare effect in the Compositor, but I am curious/wonder if it can be done purely as a Cycles material somehow only with Cycles nodes.

For example I know I can add emission node and it would kind-off like shine, but that is not the same: it is like a light casting itself on other objects and producing shadows + there is no visible thick glow around the object.

Comment: Please show an reference image. As it has been said before you can achieve a Glare effect through the Compositor, if it does not satisfy you, explain why, in what way you want to make something different

Comment: OK, will update my question with a picture

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24701/a-tube-of-light-in-a-volume-shader