# A rectangular-parallelepiped of light in a volume shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, node-editor, mathematics

(related to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24701/a-tube-of-light-in-a-volume-shader/24708#24708) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/make-gaussian-laser-beam-object-with-variable-radial-emission-profile#24678)) Well, I'm not yet (but not so far) ready for cylinders but still trying to learn!
Now let's play with rectangular-parallelepipeds and do the same thing : A shape of light inside the same bigger shape with a volume scatter. :)

The goal is to do this with 1 object, only playing with math and vector nodes connected to an emission and a volume scatter nodes in a single shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Chebhou's setups (see question for links) I found something that fits my question. here is the node setup:  [image]

But I wanted to know how to make the light inside from all sides...
here is the node setup
[image]

The important things to note are the placement of the object's origin (all rotations applied) and the value node controling the space between volume scatter and light, normalized. 0.2 means 20% up/down (Z), 20% left/right (Y) and 20% front/back (X). The last multiply node just adds strength to the light.

Comment: you did it ! I'm waiting for an [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24713/how-to-get-the-current-step-number-in-volume-render) that my help to make this effect in any object

Comment: @Chebhou That's exactly what I was about to ask :) My answer is good but looks like a workaround. I'll try to use objects geometry or something like that. BTW thanks a lot, the study of your setups allowed me to learn more in a day than in a year :)