# How to get the current step number in volume render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, volumetrics

I need to get the current step number while rendering a volume object

the step used for sampling the volume :

[image]

something like in light path node " transparent depth , ray depth "

[image]

Comment: could be something like Ray depth x step size

Comment: @Bithur it seems not, i think ray depth is not increasing inside the volume

Comment: yep, wasn't sure about that but didn't find anything else :(

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. This isn't currently exposed to the user.

The Transparent Depth value is a count of each transparent object, not distance traveled within it.

There is a Ray Depth output, but it's unclear what that does.

There is a Ray Length output, but it doesn't increase inside a volume. It's measured after the sample is taken.

Comment: ray depth is the number of bounces